# returning max values from two individual queries

Tags: sql, plsql, max

I have a query which joins two queries.

Eg:

```
select rownum from t_table1
union
select rownum1 from t_table2
```

I have used union because there are other constraints too..

Is there any way to find the max of rownum and rownum1 and combine this query with the query which finds the maximum.. ??

Comment: Please clarify that last sentence.  An example result would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX (ROWNUM)
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM FROM t_table1 
        UNION
        SELECT ROWNUM FROM t_table2)
```